# Amazon S3 to Amazon Athena to Tableau

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tableau-api, amazon-athena

I am working on a project to get data from an Amazon S3 bucket into Tableau.

The data needs to reorganised and combined from multiple .CSV files. Is Amazon Athena capable of connecting from the S3 to Tableau directly and is it relatively easy/cheap? Or should I instead look at another software package to achieve this?

I am looking to visualise the data and provide a forecast based on observed trend (may need to incorporate functions to generate data to fit linear regression).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tableau can query data from Amazon Athena.

See: [Connect to your S3 data with the Amazon Athena connector in Tableau 10.3 | Tableau Software](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/5/connect-your-s3-data-amazon-athena-connector-tableau-103-71105)

Amazon Athena can query multiple CSV files in a given path (directory) and run SQL against the data. So, it sounds like this is a feasible solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate Athena with Tableau to query your data in S3. There are plenty resource online that describe how to do that, e.g. [link 1](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/examples_amazonathena.htm), [link 2](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/5/connect-your-s3-data-amazon-athena-connector-tableau-103-71105), [link 3](http://datadiverse.com/?p=278). But obviously, tables that define meta information of your data have to be defined before hand.

[Amazon Athena pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/pricing/) is based on on the amount of data scanned by each query, i.e. 5$ per 1TB of data scanned. So it all comes down how much data you have and how it is structured, i.e. partitioning, bucketing file format etc. Here is a nice [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/) that covers these aspects.

While you prototype a dashboard there is one thing to keep in mind. By deafult, each time you would change list of parameters, filters etc, Tableau would automatically send a request to AWS Athena to execute your query. Luckily, you can disable auto querying of the data source and do it manually.